# Function to math library not being called

Tags: javascript, function, integer, sqrt

I need to get the square root of a large number, with precision, using javascript.

I've found this library BigNum which uses another called BigInteger, found here:
http://john-edwin-tobey.org/Scheme/javascript-bignum/docs/files/schemeNumber-js.html#SchemeNumber.fn
and here:
http://silentmatt.com/biginteger-docs/files/biginteger-js.html

Trying it out with jsfiddle, my call to a BigIntiger function `document.write(BigInteger(4).multiply(3));` works fine, but my call to a Bignum function `document.write(fn.sqrt(16));​` does not work.

Any ideas why?

Here's the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/tKxL6/3/

Thanks!

Comment: A quick peek at the inspector says `fn` is not defined.

Comment: Did you assign `fn` to anything as in the example? `var sn = SchemeNumber;
var fn = sn.fn;`

Comment: I just added the 
`var sn = SchemeNumber;
var fn = sn.fn;
var ns = fn["number->string"];`

from the example. Still, same problem.

Comment: Is there an `fn` on `SchemeNumber`?

Answer (score 0):

> SEC7112: Script from https://raw.github.com/silentmatt/javascript-biginteger/master/biginteger.js was blocked due to mime type mismatch
>   SEC7112: Script from https://raw.github.com/jtobey/javascript-bignum/master/schemeNumber.js was blocked due to mime type mismatch
>   SCRIPT5009: 'BigInteger' is undefined

So basically your scripts aren't being loaded because they're not being served with the correct MIME type, therefore you can't call the functions defined therein.

Comment: anyway, added `type="javascript"` to both... no dice.

Comment: That's because `javascipt` isn't a MIME type. `text/javascript` is. But that's besides the point, the SERVER has to be sending the scripts with the correct headers.

Comment: Thanks, fixed that. But the thing is, I've included both files the same way. And they are both on the same server. 

But one is working, and one is not.